# Set layer width on Konva js

Tags: javascript, konvajs

On KnovaJS, how can I set the width and height of a layer?

http://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Layer.html

I tried:

```
var layer = new Konva.Layer({x: 100, y: 200, width: 500, height: 500});
```

Only x and y properties work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Konvajs documentation](https://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Layer.html), both `width()` and `height()` are getters/setters. However for **layers** in particular, the getter will return the **stage** width/height and if you want to set the width/height, you should use `stage.width(500);` and `stage.height(500);`, respectively.